# Split linq join query in two selected lists and use Tuple to return the two lists

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, tuples

Have the following code: a entity linq query results in a select of two tables.
All data is available in the query, but can't get the result to split into two lists.

```
 public Tuple<List<sale>, List<product>>  SearchProduct(int productId = -1, string searchProduct = "")
    {
        //ToDo: searchProduct not working...gives nothing
        var companyId = DalSession.DalGetCurrentUser().Company_ID;
        using (var entity = new secondsoftEntities())
        {
            var query = (from s in entity.sales
                         join p in entity.products on s.Product_ID equals p.ProductID
                         where productId > 0 ? s.Product_ID == productId : s.Company_ID == companyId
                         select new { s, p }).ToList();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchProduct))
              {
                query = query.FindAll(x => x.p.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchProduct.ToLower()));
             } 



            // split s as List<sale> and p as List<product> to tuple output


            return Tuple.Create(new List<sale>(), new List<product>() );
        }
    }
```

In the query result I see s and p, but how the exact them as a list with there properties in it so I can return them in Tuple.

Thanx Dinand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return Tuple.Create(query.Select(x => x.s).ToList(),
                    query.Select(x => x.p).ToList());
```

Comment: Clear case of code blind. Thanx Selman. I skipt the select statement and came close with findall instate of select. Thanx again